# IIS Url Rewrite - How to prevent IIS accepting subdomain wildcard prefix xyz.domain.com in URL rewrite section

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, iis, url-rewriting

I am providing rules for redirecting our site traffic from non-wwww/http to www/https path. I have entered the following rules:

```
<rule name="Redirect to www" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myway.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.myway.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="All to https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

It is working for all network traffic but it also accept wildcard literals also in domain name like entering ww.domain.com, myname.domain.com will also lead to the site and this gives SSL certificate warning prompt by browser.

[image]

Any idea if I need to add/edit rules ?

Comment: @all any idea team ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with programming. Ultimate solution is to block the host names you don't want to support or not listed in the certificate. Of course, if you have a wildcard certificate *.somesite.com then it would remedy some.

Comment: @LexLi actually its not wildcard ssl so how can I block any host name

Comment: Add a new rule at top. In it, check incoming host name against a white list. If not matched, abort the connection or redirect to www.

Answer (score 0):

Because domain.com does not match www.domain.com it will not do the SSL connection. And because the HTTP redirect can only be done once the SSL connection is established it will not be able to do the redirect. Your only chance is do get a certificate which includes domain.com and www.domain.com.